# How to transform an object into an array and removing the empty values?

Tags: javascript

I would like to transform an object in an array, removing the objects that have no values.
So I would like to create this new array of objects.

Object I am receving:

```
{
    "61e048080589f874231c1a85": [
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",
            "xAxesProducts": 0
        },
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",
            "xAxesProducts": 1
        },
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",
            "xAxesProducts": 2
        }
    ],

    "61f2f65190c83cffb800bda3": [
        0,
        0
    ],

    "61f7000ea4f1662e206d5c0f": [
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61f7000ea4f1662e206d5c0f",
            "xAxesProducts": 0
        }
    ]
}


Expected output:
[
{ "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",  "xAxesProducts": 0}, 
{ "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",   "xAxesProducts": 1},
{ "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",  "xAxesProducts": 2}
{ "xAxesListings": "61f7000ea4f1662e206d5c0f",   "xAxesProducts": 0}
]
```

what I have tried so far

```
  var result = Object.keys(countRentals).map(function(e) {
    return countRentals[e];
```

but i am getting this where I have a lot of values with zero that I don't need.

```
[
    [
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e045a8bd8e57666714c413",
            "xAxesProducts": 0
        }
    ],
   
   
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e048080589f874231c1a85",
            "xAxesProducts": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e1763538ee44ada3c955fb",
            "xAxesProducts": 0
        },
        0
    ],
    [
        {
            "xAxesListings": "61e1770138ee44ada3c95604",
            "xAxesProducts": 0
        },
        0
    ],
    [
        0
    ],
    [
        0,
        0
    ],
   
      });
```

I also have tried this:

```
 var arr = Object.entries(countRentals);
```

and in this case I am getting this:

```
[
    [
        "61e045a8bd8e57666714c413",
        [
            {
                "xAxesListings": "61e045a8bd8e57666714c413",
                "xAxesProducts": 0
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "61e0474843bbc2ab0d553633",
        [
            {
                "xAxesListings": "61e0474843bbc2ab0d553633",
                "xAxesProducts": 0
            }
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Sounds good. What have you tried? Making an attempt is important - it shows you are trying to learn and shows others where you need help.

Comment: @Kinglish I added with the things I have tried and the results I got.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions could look as follows:

```
Object.values(yourStructure)
    .flat()
    .filter(v => typeof v === 'object');
```